# Retrieve return type of function w/o calling the function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, tsc

Say I have a function like this in TypeScript:

```
export const foo = function(){

   return {
     a: 1,
     b: true,
     c: 'bar'
   }

};
```

if I import this function into another file:

```
import {foo} from './foobar';
```

My question is - is there a way to get the *return type of `foo`* **without** actually calling `foo`?

Comment: does this work? https://schneidenbach.gitbooks.io/typescript-cookbook/get-the-return-type-of-a-function.html

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want but seems kind of hackish

Comment: if you add an answer I will def upvote but might wait to see if there is something better before selecting it as accepted answer

Comment: Isn't it just `ReturnType<typeof foo>` ?

Comment: where's the love for the OP when it's needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible with Typescript 2.8

```
let foo = function() {
   return {
     a: 1,
     b: true,
     c: 'bar'
   }
};

type ComplexObj = ReturnType<typeof foo>;  // {a: number, b: boolean, c: string}
```